# Get the right hand side variables of an R formula

Tags: r, class, formula

I'm writing my first S3 class and associated methods and I would like to know how to subset my input data set in order to keep only the variables specified in the formula?

```
data(iris)
f <- Species~Petal.Length + Petal.Width
```

With `model.frame(f,iris)` I get a subset with all the variables in the formula. How to automatically keep only the right hand side variables (in the example `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width`)?

Comment: `model.frame(f,iris)[, -1]`?

Comment: You don't need `as.formula` here.  `Species~Petal.Length + Petal.Width` is already a formula.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want `labels` and `terms`; see `?labels`, `?terms`, and `?terms.object`.

```
labels(terms(f))
# [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

In particular, `labels.terms` returns the `"term.labels"` attribute of a `terms` object, which excludes the LHS variable.

Answer (score 20):

If you have a function in your formula, e.g., `log`, and want to subset the data frame based on the variables, you can use `get_all_vars`. This will ignore the function and extract the untransformed variables:

```
f2 <- Species ~ log(Petal.Length) + Petal.Width

get_all_vars(f2[-2], iris)

    Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            1.4         0.2
2            1.4         0.2
3            1.3         0.2
4            1.5         0.2
...
```

If you just want the variable names, `all.vars` is a very helpful function:

```
all.vars(f2[-2])

[1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

The `[-2]` is used to exclude the left hand side.

Comment: This won't take interactions into account, e.g. `get_all_vars(mpg ~ hp * cyl, mtcars)`.

Comment: @jay.sf This is the intended behaviour of `get_all_vars`.

Comment: Sure, great command I didn't know before, I intended just a little side note for someone (like me) who expected the interactions terms to also appear as e.g. in `labels(terms(mpg ~ hp * cyl))` from the other solution.

Answer (score 10):

One way is to use subsetting to remove the LHS from the formula. Then you can use `model.frame` on this:

```
f[-2]
~Petal.Length + Petal.Width

model.frame(f[-2],iris)
    Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            1.4         0.2
2            1.4         0.2
3            1.3         0.2
4            1.5         0.2
5            1.4         0.2
6            1.7         0.4
...
```

Comment: I like this answer because it removes the dependent part, no matter the number of terms in it. `formula(a + b ~ c +d)[-2]`

Answer (score 7):

The package [**formula.tools**](https://github.com/decisionpatterns/formula.tools) has a number of functions to make life easier working with formulas. In your case:

```
> formula.tools::rhs.vars(f)
[1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Relying on base R can be dangerous because the left hand side can be missing, meaning that element 1 no longer refers to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f_rhs` function from the `rlang`package to extract the right handside of the formula and combine it with `all.vars`

```
> f <- Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width
> 
> # RHS
> rlang::f_rhs(f)
Petal.Length + Petal.Width
> all.vars(rlang::f_rhs(f))
[1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
> 
> # LHS
> rlang::f_lhs(f)
Species
> all.vars(rlang::f_lhs(f))
[1] "Species"
```