# How to access formula terms of a brms model in R

Tags: r, brms

I am working with a model developed using the `brms` package in R. I need to access the formula terms of the model but am unable to do so.

This question explains how to do exactly what I want in base R: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330739.

```
data(iris)
f <- Species~Petal.Length + Petal.Width
labels(terms(f))
# [1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

In brms the formula appears to be stored in `<model>$formula`, but calling `label(terms(<model>$formula))` does not work.

```
library(brms)

prior1 <- prior(normal(0,10), class = b) +
  prior(cauchy(0,2), class = sd)
fit1 <- brm(count ~ zAge + zBase * Trt + (1|patient),
            data = epilepsy, family = poisson(), prior = prior1)
View(fit1)

labels(terms(fit1$formula))
Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : 
  no terms component nor attribute

labels(terms(fit1))
Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : 
  no terms component nor attribute
```

I have also experimented with `?brms::brmsterms` and `?brms::brmsformula` but have been unable to extract the formula terms in the same way as the SO question I linked to for base R. Is that possible?

Comment: it's not a formula in the way that `f` is a formula, try `labels(terms(as.formula(fit1$formula)))` there is a full page on this specific class `?brmsformula`

Comment: `labels(terms(fit1$formula$formula))`

Comment: Both of your solutions work on the sample data. But when applied to my actual code I get `Error in terms.formula(as.formula(object$formula)) : invalid power in formula`.

Comment: Specifically, `as.formula(<my real formula>)` works but `terms(as.formula(<my real formula>)) fails with that error. My real formula contains exponents. Is that the issue?

Comment: Hmm. My issue seems very much like what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010732/error-in-terms-formulaformula-data-data-invalid-power-in-formula/55010945#55010945

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the real formula you're using?  If you have an unprotected `^` operator in it which you meant to denote exponentiation, it probably isn't doing what you intended anyway ...